# TimeSpan to Custom string like HH:mm:ss

Tags: c#, .net, timespan, time-format

I would like to convert

```
var delta = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

to string like `00:00:01`

I try this `delta.ToString(@"0:\\hh\\:mm\\:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

But nothing is working fine. 
Also I cannot find here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx correct way to do it.

Method `ToString()` does not help so i need in format lie `hh:mm:ss`.

[image]
Any clue?

Comment: You mean *to string like 00:00:10* ?

Comment: Try : var delta = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).ToString("c");  See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use :

```
delta.ToString(); // 00:00:10
```

which does the trick for you ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NJXc11))

Or try this:

```
var str = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", delta.Hours, delta.Minutes, delta.Seconds);
```

You can build an extension method if you use it a lot:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToCustomString(this TimeSpan span)
    {
        return string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
string strSpan = delta.ToCustomString();
```

Comment: No it is not it gives seconds with milliseconds like 00:08:59.4199537

Comment: It is working on my .NET Version.

Comment: Well I use .net 4.5 and returns 00:08:59.4199537

Comment: Check this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NJXc11

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2015 and it  works as I see, fiddle is wrong,,,

Comment: @Dimi What do you mean fiddle is wrong ? It produces `00:00:10`

Comment: Yes, man I will add a screenshot to my question,

Comment: @Dimi i can't see any edit in your question.

Comment: @Dimi check my edited answer.

Comment: Yep, the last code is great!

Comment: You can do the same on a TimeSpan's ToString method. You can pass the format in the ToString() method of the TimeSpan itself. No need to use string.format(). Example in my answer.

Comment: Only reason the fiddle is right is because the TimeSpan is 10 seconds, round. Try with `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1234567);` and it will show milliseconds. Ramazan has the right answer

Answer (score 42):

Just use the ToString(String format) method of TimeSpan, passing in the format you require.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx

E.g.

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10000);
var output = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: So much better than topvoted/accepted answer

Comment: This won't work if the "hh" part exceeds 24. It will simply provide the HOURS part for "hh", i.e., if TimeSpan is 36 hours + something, it will display 12 for "hh". You could achieve the correct output for that case by using the following - 
`String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds)`

Answer (score 4):

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;

public class Class1
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      TimeSpan[] spans = { TimeSpan.Zero, new TimeSpan(-14, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                           new TimeSpan(1, 2, 3), 
                           new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 250), 
                           new TimeSpan(99, 23, 59, 59, 999),
                           new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0), 
                           new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 25) };
      string[] fmts = { "c", "g", "G", @"hh\:mm\:ss", "%m' min.'" };
      foreach (TimeSpan span in spans)
      {
         foreach (string fmt in fmts)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", fmt, span.ToString(fmt));

         Console.WriteLine();
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       c: 00:00:00
//       g: 0:00:00
//       G: 0:00:00:00.0000000
//       hh\:mm\:ss: 00:00:00
//       %m' min.': 0 min.
//       
//       c: -14.00:00:00
//       g: -14:0:00:00
//       G: -14:00:00:00.0000000
//       hh\:mm\:ss: 00:00:00
//       %m' min.': 0 min.
//       
//       c: 01:02:03
//       g: 1:02:03
//       G: 0:01:02:03.0000000
//       hh\:mm\:ss: 01:02:03
//       %m' min.': 2 min.
//       
//       c: 00:00:00.2500000
//       g: 0:00:00.25
//       G: 0:00:00:00.2500000
//       hh\:mm\:ss: 00:00:00
//       %m' min.': 0 min.
//       
//       c: 99.23:59:59.9990000
//       g: 99:23:59:59.999
//       G: 99:23:59:59.9990000
//       hh\:mm\:ss: 23:59:59
//       %m' min.': 59 min.
//       
//       c: 03:00:00
//       g: 3:00:00
//       G: 0:03:00:00.0000000
//       hh\:mm\:ss: 03:00:00
//       %m' min.': 0 min.
//       
//       c: 00:00:00.0250000
//       g: 0:00:00.025
//       G: 0:00:00:00.0250000
//       hh\:mm\:ss: 00:00:00
//       %m' min.': 0 min.
```

Also if you want a custom made,

```
public static class TimeSpanExt
{
  public static string ToStringMyFormat(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
  {
     return timeSpan.Days.ToString("00") + ":" + timeSpan.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + timeSpan.Minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + timeSpan.Seconds.ToString("00") + ":" + timeSpan.Milliseconds.ToString("00");
  }
}
```